# Calculate column in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have table like this

```
 id buildingId order  title
 --------------------------
  1      2      null  test1
  2      2      null  test2
  3      2      null  test3
  4      3      null  test4
  5      3      null  test5
  6      5      null  test6
```

I need calculate order value for every row. I need after execute sql query get this table

```
 id buildingId order  title
  1      2      0     test1
  2      2      1     test2
  3      2      2     test3
  4      3      0     test4
  5      3      1     test5
  6      5      0     test6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you getting the values for order from? Is it another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, buildingID, [order], title,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY buildingID
                                ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
UPDATE recordList
SET [order] = rn - 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7323a/1)